# Getting specified value of dropdown

Tags: javascript

I have two different  dropdowns. First one have 3 values, like: SuperAdmin, Admin and Operator, if one of these is selected
it show the anoter dropdown removing "DisplayNone" class

```
                   <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label class="col-md-5 control-label"> Perfiles:</label>
                        <div class="col-md-7 text-left">
                            <select id="dropPerfiles" name="dropPerfiles" class="form-control">
                                <option value="0">Seleccione</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6 onliIndirecto DisplayNone">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label text-right labelSmall"> Sucursal:</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6 text-left">
                            <select name="branchOfficeId" id="branchOfficeId" class="form-control"></select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

js:

```
$("#dropPerfiles").on("change", function () {
            $(".onliIndirecto").removeClass("DisplayNone");
        });
```

Problem is when I want to only display second dropdown if Admin is selected (the other ones can´t display it). 
How can I get specific value of my dropdown?

Chrome Html:

```
<select id="dropPerfiles" name="dropPerfiles" class="form-control" data-fv-field="dropPerfiles">
<option value="">Seleccione</option>
<option value="616E7014-338C-4395-8DF0-B7D5162597EE">SuperAdmin</option>
<option value="7579ED4F-91A9-4774-B1EE-05A274533AF5">Administrador</option>
<option value="B3611BC0-34C7-4486-B916-5B715CE83B5C">Operador</option></select>
```

Help is very appreciated. Regards

Comment: `$(this).val()` will return the value of the dropdown in the `.change()` function.

Comment: Why do you have such random values in your options? Why not `<option value="1">SuperAdmin</option>`?

Comment: it popiulate from database, so I know I receive, SuperAdmin, Admin, and Operator @Barmar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `this.value` to get the value of the dropdown.

```
$("#dropPerfiles").on("change", function () {
    $(".onliIndirecto").toggleClass("DisplayNone", this.value != "7579ED4F-91A9-4774-B1EE-05A274533AF5");
});
```

If you don't want to use those random values from the DB, you can use `$(this).find("option:selected").text()` to get the text of the selected option, and compare that with `"Administratador"`.

```
$("#dropPerfiles").on("change", function () {
    $(".onliIndirecto").toggleClass("DisplayNone", $(this).find("option:selected").text() != "Administratador");
});
```

Comment: Can you explain me how an I compare it with administrator?

Comment: Exactly the same way that I compared the value with the random number. Just replace `this.value` with that expression.

Comment: What kind of programmer are you if you can't put together basic operations like this?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#dropPerfiles").on("change", function () {
   var selected = $(this + "option:selected"); //get selected
   var text= selected.text(); //get text
   var value= selected.val(); //get value

     if(text== "SuperAdmin"){
       //do stuff
           $(".onliIndirecto").removeClass("DisplayNone");
      }

      //OR

     if(value == "your value"){
       //do stuff
          $(".onliIndirecto").removeClass("DisplayNone");
      }

});
```